# Purpose of the "split" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed there is a tag called [split](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/split) without any description. The list of 49 questions tagged right now includes all sorts of questions: splitting text files, splitting large archives, splitting screen, splitting video file, split tunnelling, partitioning (separating or "splitting" home and root) etc.

Does it make sense to have this tag around without a proper definition and usage?

Comment: Does upvoting this question mean 1) good question; 2) good idea, bad tag or 3) good tag?

Comment: +1 good question! ;P

Comment: @dessert or maybe just "[good boy](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Good%20boy)"!

Answer (score 15):

## remove this tag

I vote to delete this thing.

One could think about making it solely about GNU coreutils' `/usr/bin/split`, but in my opinion this program does not really need a tag of its own.